# Django Customer with onetoone relationship with User - how to create the fields for that model when creating User?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, one-to-one

Here is my problem - upon creation of User in django i want to also create Customer with Onetoone relationship. I was able to get this working but problem started when I wasn't able to also create fields - dob and mobile. (User is default django user)

My forms.py

```
    class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
    mobile = CharField(max_length=30)
    
class CreateCustomerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['mobile', 'dob']
```

My models.py

```
class Customer(Model):
    user = OneToOneField(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    mobile = CharField(max_length=12,null=True)
    dob = DateField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

My views.py

```
def customer_registration(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            group = Group.objects.get(name='customer')
            user.groups.add(group)
            Customer.objects.create(
                user=user, 
            )
            messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + username)
            return redirect('index')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'signup.html', context)
```

I need to add 2 more fields into that Customer model (dob=form.dob, mobile=form.mobile), I was trying to have second form for this but it wouldn't work. This is what I have tried:

```
def customer_registration(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()
    form2 = CreateCustomerForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()

            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            group = Group.objects.get(name='customer')
            user.groups.add(group)
            if request.method == 'POST':
                form2 = CreateCustomerForm(request.POST)
                
                mobile = form2['mobile']

                Customer.objects.create(
                user=user, mobile=mobile)
                messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + username)
                return redirect('index')
            else:
                print('Error')
    context = {'form': form, 'form2': form2}
    return render(request, 'signup.html', context)
```

and:

```
def customer_registration(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()
    form2 = CreateCustomerForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        form2 = CreateCustomerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            mobile = form2.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            group = Group.objects.get(name='customer')
            user.groups.add(group)
            Customer.objects.create(
                user=user, mobile=mobile,
            )
            messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + username)
            return redirect('index')
    context = {'form': form, 'form2': form2}
    return render(request, 'signup.html', context)
```

I really got stock on this one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe only problem is that your `CreateCustomerForm` does not assign a value to the `user` field of the `Customer`, you can set the `.user` of the `.instance` wrapped in the second form (`form2`):

```
def customer_registration(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()
    form2 = CreateCustomerForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        form2 = CreateCustomerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            form2.instance.user = user  # 🖘 assign to the user of the customer
            form2.save()
            username = user.username
            messages.success(request, f'Account was created for {username}')
            return redirect('index')
    context = {'form': form, 'form2': form2}
    return render(request, 'signup.html', context)
```